# Error converting valid SQL query into valid HQL

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, hql

I'm running a SpringBoot Java application which is currently using hibernate-core 6.1.7.Final. I have a valid SQL query that gives me the results I need which I need to convert into HQL so my app can run the query and return the same results. However, I keep getting an error during app start up. I've had multiple different errors while trying to fix the HQL, the current error based on the current version of the code shown below is:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component at index 0 has no alias, but alias is required`

Below is the working SQL query that gives the correct results:

```
SELECT PARENT.* 
      , CHILD1.* 
    FROM [dbo].[PARENT] PARENT 
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[CHILD] CHILD1 
      ON CHILD1.ParentId = PARENT.id 
  INNER JOIN ( 
      SELECT parentId, MAX(effectivetimestamp) as MaxEff, Max([createdtimestamp]) as MaxCre 
        FROM [dbo].[CHILD] as CHILD2
        WHERE CHILD2.effectivetimestamp < Cast(Getutcdate() at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'GMT Standard Time' AS DATETIME2) 
        GROUP BY parentId 
      ) CHILD2 
    ON CHILD2.parentId = CHILD1.parentId 
    AND CHILD2.MaxEff = CHILD1.effectiveTimestamp 
    AND CHILD2.MaxCre = CHILD1.createdTimestamp
```

dbo.PARENT has a one to many relationship with dbo.CHILD. dbo.CHILD has the columns effectiveTimestamp and this query is returning all Parents with the current active Child (latest effectiveTimestamp value that is not future dated for each parent).

Below are the Java entity classes for Parent and Child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Child> child;

    public List<Child> getChild() {
        return child;
    }

    public void setChild(List<Child> child) {
        this.child = child;
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
public class Child {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Parent parent;
    
    @Column(name = "effectiveTimestamp", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime effectiveTimestamp;
    
    @Column(name = "createdTimestamp", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdTimestamp;
    

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getEffectiveTimestamp() {
        return effectiveTimestamp;
    }

    public void setEffectiveTimestamp(LocalDateTime effectiveTimestamp) {
        this.effectiveTimestamp = effectiveTimestamp;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedTimestamp() {
        return createdTimestamp;
    }

    public void setCreatedTimestamp(LocalDateTime createdTimestamp) {
        this.createdTimestamp = createdTimestamp;
    }

}
```

And this is my current attempt at the native hibernate query that is currently failing. I want it to return all Parent objects in the table, joining only the current active Child to the Parent.

```
      @Query(value = "SELECT PARENT, CHILD1 FROM Parent PARENT "
              + " INNER JOIN Child CHILD1 "
              + "   ON CHILD1.parent.id = PARENT.id "
              + "   INNER JOIN "
              + "  ( SELECT CHILD1.parent.id, MAX(CHILD1.effectiveTimestamp) as MaxEff, MAX(CHILD1.createdTimestamp) as MaxCre "
              + "  FROM Child as CHILD2 "
              + "     WHERE CHILD1.effectiveTimestamp <= :currentTimestamp "
              + "     GROUP BY CHILD1.parent.id "
              + "     ) CHILD2 "
              + "   ON CHILD2.parent.id = CHILD1.parent.id "
              + "   AND CHILD2.MaxEff = CHILD1.effectiveTimestamp "
              + "   AND CHILD2.MaxCre = CHILD1.createdTimestamp " )
      Optional<List<Parent>> getAllActiveChildByParent(@Param("currentTimestamp") LocalDateTime currentTimestamp);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Following the comment from Andrey B. Panfilov below I have added the missing alias which can be seen below.

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT PARENT, CHILD1 FROM Parent PARENT "
              + " INNER JOIN Child CHILD1 "
              + "   ON CHILD1.parent.id = PARENT.id "
              + "   INNER JOIN "
              + "  ( SELECT CHILD1.parent.id as NEWALIAS, MAX(CHILD1.effectiveTimestamp) as MaxEff, MAX(CHILD1.createdTimestamp) as MaxCre "
              + "  FROM Child as CHILD2 "
              + "     WHERE CHILD1.effectiveTimestamp <= :currentTimestamp "
              + "     GROUP BY CHILD1.parent.id "
              + "     ) CHILD2 "
              + "   ON CHILD2.parent.id = CHILD1.parent.id "
              + "   AND CHILD2.MaxEff = CHILD1.effectiveTimestamp "
              + "   AND CHILD2.MaxCre = CHILD1.createdTimestamp " )
      Optional<List<Parent>> getAllActiveChildByParent(@Param("currentTimestamp") LocalDateTime currentTimestamp);
```

However I am now getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not resolve attribute 'parent' of 'java.lang.Object[]'
```

By breaking down the hibernate query I believe the error is coming from the 2nd inner join, but I can't see what in that section is causing the error.

Comment: it is asking to define alias for `CHILD1.parent.id`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, are you referring to adding the alias to the group by statement e.g. 



`GROUP BY CHILD1.parent.id as ALIAS`



If so then I get a 'no viable alternative at input' error 



`Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.ParsingException: line 1:340 no viable alternative at input 'SELECTPARENT,CHILD1FROMParentPARENTINNERJOINChildCHILD1ONCHILD1.parent.id=PARENT.idINNERJOIN(SELECTCHILD1.parent.id,MAX(CHILD1.effectiveTimestamp)asMaxEff,MAX(CHILD1.createdTimestamp)asMaxCreFROMChildasCHILD2WHERECHILD1.effectiveTimestamp<=:currentTimestampGROUPBYCHILD1.parent.idALIAS'`

Comment: If you are referring to adding to the join statements  `ON CHILD1.parent.id = PARENT.id` then I understandably get this error `Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.ParsingException: line 1:92 mismatched input 'AS' expecting {<EOF>, ',', '.', '[', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '||', AND, BY, CROSS, DAY, FULL, GROUP, HOUR, INNER, JOIN, LEFT, MINUTE, MONTH, NANOSECOND, OR, ORDER, OUTER, QUARTER, RIGHT, SECOND, WEEK, WHERE, YEAR}`

Comment: `SELECT CHILD1.parent.id` -> `SELECT CHILD1.parent.id AS parent_id`, `ON CHILD2.parent.id = CHILD1.parent.id` -> `ON CHILD2.parent_id = CHILD1.parent.id`

Comment: Thanks, that's resolved the alias issue, I'm now getting this exception instead `Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not resolve attribute 'parent' of 'java.lang.Object[]'`

Answer (score 0):

Using the alias I added off the back of the comment from Andrey B. Panfilov, I had to use that alias in my second inner join to fix the 'Could not resolve attribute' error. The hibernate query below now works.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT PARENT, CHILD1 FROM Parent PARENT "
              + " INNER JOIN Child CHILD1 "
              + "   ON CHILD1.parent.id = PARENT.id "
              + "   INNER JOIN "
              + "  ( SELECT CHILD1.parent.id as NEWALIAS, MAX(CHILD1.effectiveTimestamp) as MaxEff, MAX(CHILD1.createdTimestamp) as MaxCre "
              + "  FROM Child as CHILD2 "
              + "     WHERE CHILD1.effectiveTimestamp <= :currentTimestamp "
              + "     GROUP BY CHILD1.parent.id "
              + "     ) CHILD2 "
              + "   ON NEWALIAS = CHILD2.parent.id "
              + "   AND CHILD2.MaxEff = CHILD1.effectiveTimestamp "
              + "   AND CHILD2.MaxCre = CHILD1.createdTimestamp " )
      Optional<List<Parent>> getAllActiveChildByParent(@Param("currentTimestamp") LocalDateTime currentTimestamp);
```